# Lua syntax highlighting latex for arXiv

Tags: pdf, lua, latex, syntax-highlighting

I have a latex file which needed to include snippets of Lua code (for display, not execution), so I used the [minted](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) package. It requires latex to be run with the `latex -shell-escape` flag.

I am trying to upload a PDF submission to [arXiv](http://arxiv.org). The site requires these to be submitted as `.tex`, `.sty` and `.bbl`, which they will automatically compile to PDF from latex. When I tried to submit to arXiv, I learned that there was no way for them to activate the `-shell-escape` flag.

So I was wondering if any of you knew a way to highlight Lua code in latex without the `-shell-escape` flag. I tried the listings package, but I can't get it to work for Lua on my Ubuntu computer.

Comment: Try [GNU Source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) which support Lua input and LaTeX output.

Comment: Try also http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set whichever style you want inline using [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings). It's predefined `Lua` language has all the keywords and associated styles identified, so you can just change it to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{lua}{
  language=[5.1]Lua,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
  stringstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{black!50}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=lua]
-- defines a factorial function
    function fact (n)
      if n == 0 then
        return 1
      else
        return n * fact(n-1)
      end
    end

    print("enter a number:")
    a = io.read("*number")        -- read a number
    print(fact(a))
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay so [lhf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107090/lhf) found a good solution by suggesting the [GNU source-hightlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) package. I basically took out each snippet of lua code from the latex file, put it into an appropriately named `[snippet].lua` file and ran the following on it to generate a `[snippet]-lua.tex` :

`source-highlight -s lua -f latex -i [snippet].lua -o [snippet]-lua.tex`

And then I included each such file into the main latex file using :

`\input{[snippet]-lua}`

The result really isn't as nice as that of the minted package, but I am tired of trying to convince the arXiv admin to support minted...